# How to ensemble forecasts in R using weights

Tags: r

I have a couple forecasts and was trying to figure out how to merge the two according to some criterion that is widely used.

In part one, I split the data and compared the forecasts against the actual balues using Forest_comb.

```
library(forecast)
library(ForecastCombinations)
y1 = rnorm(100)
train = y1[1:90]
test = y1[91:100]
fit1 = auto.arima(train)
fit2 = ets(train)
forc1 = forecast(fit1, n=10)$mean
forc2 = forecast(fit2, n=10)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc1,forc2)
forc_all
?Forecast_comb
fitted <- Forecast_comb(obs = test ,fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")$fitted
fitted
```

In part two, I rebuilt the whole model on the entire data and forecast out by ten values. How can one merge the two values together according to some criterion?

```
fit3 = auto.arima(y1)
fit4 = ets(y1)
forc3 = forecast(fit3, n=20)$mean
forc4 = forecast(fit4, n=20)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc3,forc4)
forc_all
fitted <- Forecast_comb(obs = y1[91:100] ,fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")$fitted
fitted
```

Thanks for the help

The reason that I am using ForecastCombination is that it includes procedures for popular combination strategies. I thought that perhaps that function could be modified to perform the desired ensembling.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a lot of Kaggle competitions where people share/discuss their scripts, I'd say that by far the most common and most effective way is simply to manually weight and add your predictions.

```
pacman::p_load(forecast)
pacman::p_load(ForecastCombinations)
y1 = rnorm(100)
train = y1[1:90]
test = y1[91:100]
fit1 = auto.arima(train)
fit2 = ets(train)
forc1 = forecast(fit1, n=10)$mean
forc2 = forecast(fit2, n=10)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc1,forc2)
forc_all
?Forecast_comb
fitted_1 <- Forecast_comb(obs = test ,fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")$fitted
fitted_1

fit3 = auto.arima(y1)
fit4 = ets(y1)
forc3 = forecast(fit3, n=20)$mean
forc4 = forecast(fit4, n=20)$mean
forc_all = cbind(forc3,forc4)
forc_all
fitted_2 <- Forecast_comb(obs = y1[91:100] ,fhat = as.matrix(forc_all), Averaging_scheme = "best")$fitted
fitted_2

# By far the most common way to combine/weight is simply:
fitted <- fitted_2*.5+fitted_1*.5
fitted
```

One might ask if you should use equal weights or how to know what to make the weights. This is usually determined by

(a) naive, equal weighting if that's all you have time for and it seems to work fine

(b) iterating with a holdout or cross-validation sample(s), being careful not to overfit

Some people try to take more fancy approaches. It's easy to mess that up, however if you get it right then it can lead you to a more optimal forecast.

The model-based and other more fancy approaches are things like creating another stage of the modeling process wherein your predictions on a holdout sample are the **X** matrix and the outcome variable is the actual **y** for that sample.

Also, check out [Erin LeDell's approach](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/master/h2o-r/ensemble) in `h2oEnsemble`.